# International phone number format in the input

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have an input like this one:

```
<textarea name='phone_number' id='phone_number' cols='80' rows='1'><? echo $_POST['phone_number']; ?></textarea>
```

well, i made a function in PHP to validate the phone number( check that's not empty and no chars in it, just + and numbers)

and ***now***, i want to format it inline in that input with some JQuery/JavaScript thing, but the format i'm thinking something **International** like if i have:

`0016073222153` to be `+1 607-322-2153`

`0049329351525` to be `+49 329-351-525`

any ideas how can i do this? appreciate it ! thanks!

Comment: Every country has their own formatting rules, this isn't straightforward.

Comment: so, how can i make like a general rule to do that ? i need some kind of format :(

Comment: You need to explain more about what you are trying to do.  Those two examples are not enough.

Comment: i want if some one types a number like the one above to change it/ format it in a new for like +x-xxx-xxx-xxxx

Comment: @Jimmy, That comment does not add any new information.

Comment: what can i say more? i want to make the new number in this format: replace the 00 to a plus (+) and then one number and then this char(-) and after that 3 number and (-) and after that again 3 numbers and (-) and at last 4 numbers.... i hope i cleared what i want a little bit :(

Comment: So you're okay with a format like: +4-932-935-1525

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming a lot but it fits your use case and might get you started

```
var num1 = "0016073222153",
    num2 = "0049329351525";

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('body').append(
        phoneFormat(num1) + "<br />" + 
        phoneFormat(num2)
    );
});

function phoneFormat(num) {

    num = num.replace(/^0+/, '');
    num = num.replace(/[^0-9]/, '');

    if (num.length == 11) {

        if (num.substr(0, 1) == 1) num = "+1 " + num.substr(1, 3) + "-" + num.substr(4, 3) + "-" + num.substr(7, 4);
        else num = "+" + num.substr(0, 2) + " " + num.substr(2, 3) + "-" + num.substr(5, 3) + "-" + num.substr(8, 3);
    }

    return num;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tnv2m/

Comment: yes, this is kind of what i need, could you please make an example of code how can i use it with the input to make the changes of the phone_number instantly inline of the input ? thanks!

Comment: it's not working :(, i mean i can't type like 00 and it's not formatting the number after

Comment: You don't need leading zero's so they're removed immediately

Comment: sure i do, because if the number is `0016073222153` to be `+1 607-322-2153`

Comment: I don't know what to say, if you type those numbers in one by one you get exactly that result.

Comment: :(, i'm trying to type the numbers but it's not working, not copy paste but typing...

Comment: Came for PHP Code, leaving with JS. And the fiddle is still up. Big Thank you @SteveRobbins 
for anyone sarching like me: http://jsfiddle.net/q1g3pb8d/1/

Answer (score 0):

For the country code, this is not very complicated (I think), just a bit of grunt work.

You can get the list of country codes [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes). Then you fetch the first digit and determine from the calling code table if there's a next digit you should read; repeat until you have determined the country code.

For the rest of the numbers you could just do something like:

```
join('-', str_split($nr, 3));
```

This gives you groups of 3 digits, separated by a dash.

Comment: can't i make like a general rule like replace the 00 with plus(+) and then to be this format x-xxx-xxx-xxxx ?thanks !

Comment: @Jimmy of course you can replace `00` with `+` but the country code is not always the same length :)

Comment: so how do you think Jack is appropriate to format the phone number? i have from US and UK for example :(

Comment: For `0049xxxx`, you replace `00` with `+`, then read first number; from the table you can see that codes starting with `4` have at least 2 digits, so you read one more and you end up with `49` ... so then you have `+49`; the rest of the numbers are the local part.

Comment: it's too complicated this way, i want something more easy

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to do that in universal way. Each country got different formatting, different zone numbers and so on. W/o exact database that would keep all that formatting rules, you end nowhere. Either format for countries you know the rules for or drop the idea.